# IOS App not installing

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed my iOS App and used developer provisional profile(Free account). When I give my App to other users for testing they aren't able to install the app on their device with error unable to download App "MYAPP" could not be downloaded at this time. I don't find any solution for that please suggest me something.

Comment: How did you share the build ?

Comment: If they are downloading the app using testflight or diawi, then you should add their device's UDID in provisioning profile to enable their device to download your testing app.

Comment: are you added the UDID in your developer portal

Comment: i am using diawi for testing

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't think the free account has the capability to add UDID? Mine is the free account, I don't see the Certificates, Identifiers and Provisioning page.

Comment: provisioning profile issue , delete the installed provisioning profile and downalod and reinstalled the provisioning profile again reset provisioning profile in build settings.. and then rebuild.

Comment: can i add a device in free developer provisional certificate ?

Comment: @sunielkalwani check my answer

Comment: NO you can not add device in free account.. you should enroll to Apple developer account.

Comment: @sunielkalwani Is that helped?

Comment: @imad can i use testflight for testing with free account . i am little confused because i am new in iphone devlopment

Comment: @sunielkalwani No, you cannot use TestFlight. For TestFlight, you need access to iTunesConnect which is only for Apple Developer program members.

Comment: @imad ok .. thanx  bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free Apple developer account doesn't have the capability to distribute the app. You need to have the either Apple Developer or Enterprise program.
You cannot even add the devices, check below for more information. Check the Sign in with Apple ID or 1st column for your case.

As a free account, you have access only to **Xcode developer tools, Xcode Beta releases, Developer Forums, Bug Reporter & Test on the device** (debugging).

[image]

Source :

[Apple developer portal - Choosing a Membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enroll to apple developer account either for App Store or Enterprise based on your requirement.

**Ad-hoc**

You need to add UDID for users device to sucessfully install build. Create build using developer certificate and profile. It can be distributed and installed though iTune

**App - Store**

This lets you upload build on app store. Combination of distribution certificate and profile.

For above cases ensure that you have created build using valid profile.

Comment: i have a free developer account so can i add other device or not

Comment: No you need to enroll for apple developer program

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you need to purchase/ enroll in development program in order to create installable ipa.

Then you need to add testing devices UDID (user can get it from iTunes) to testing devices in your apple developer account, then you can create a valid ipa for testing.